# Making TableView Pull from 1 of 2 NSURLRequests

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsurlrequest, nsjsonserialization

I am having trouble telling my table view which NSURLRequest it should target. I can get a basic table view to load with a single query, but am trying to make it pull the json string from a different URL if certain segmented controls are active.

These first three lines of code work by themselves

```
NSString *urlA1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/json_books.php?
item_id=%@",itemId];

NSURL *urlA2 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlA1];

NSURLRequest *requestA = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlA2];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestA delegate:self];
```

However, if I include the following three lines after the first three, the tableview loads the json from the first NSURLRequest, then immediately flickers and shows content from the string below:

```
NSString *urlB1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/json_movies.php?
item_id=%@",itemId];

NSURL *urlB2 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlB1];

NSURLRequest *requestB = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlB2];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestB delegate:self];
```

I am pulling the result into the table view with these lines of code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse 
*)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    items = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    [mainTableView reloadData];
}
```

Does anyone know why I am unable to specify which NSURLRequest I would like the tableview to target? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you Want to Show Data from Both The URL ?

if yes then You have to take `NSMUtableArray` and initialize the Array in `ViewDidload` before Firing the Request. And You have to Add the Objects into the Array from Each URL.

Example:

```
[DataArray addObject:@"Yourdata"];

[Yourtable reloadData];
```

If You need to Separate the data as per Segmented Control then Save Your data in Separate Array.

```
MyfirstArray= @"Data from URL 1";

MySecondArray= @"Data from URL 2";


-(IBAction)SegmentChange:(Id)sender
{
if(segmented.selectedSegmentIndex==0)

{
items=MyfirstArray;

[mytable reloadData];

}

else

{
items=MysecondtArray;

[mytable reloadData];
}

}
```

Also You can take Switch statement.

Comment: I will ultimately have a tableview that pulls the data from one of the two URLs depending on which segmented control is active. I do not plan on merging the data from both the URLs.

Comment: ok Then you have two Choice 1. You can take Two different Array and Store data According to Segmented control selected segmentedIndex. 

2. You can Call the Request on Segmented Control Value changed Action.

Comment: Thank you I will probably go with the first option. I am still having trouble figuring out why I cannot specify which of the two NSURLRequests is targeted though. According to my code, does that tableview just pull the most recent NSURLRequest?

Comment: Thank you!! I will definately use this!